# php regex match & replace html a tags exclude domain

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I found links and replace with nofollow. But I need if "<a(.*)" line contains "google.com" stop replace.

This is my code:

```
preg_replace('#(<a\s)#is', '\\1rel="nofollow noreferrer ugc" target="_blank" ', $post->content);
```

Inputs:

```
<a href="https://www.burtinet.com/">Hosting</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a>
```

Output:

```
<a rel="nofollow noreferrer ugc" target="_blank" href="https://www.burtinet.com/">Hosting</a>
<a rel="nofollow noreferrer ugc" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a>
```

I need:

```
<a rel="nofollow noreferrer ugc" target="_blank" href="https://www.burtinet.com/">Hosting</a>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Search</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it should do what you are looking for, I just updated your regular expression to ignore replacing if it contains google. we can enhance it a bit more and be specific to the **href** if you would like to.

```
$output  = preg_replace('#((?!.*google)(<a\s))#is', '\\1rel="nofollow noreferrer ugc" target="_blank" ', $post->content);
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/LHe3bU/3 not match